# Point to bound variables in scope

Tags: search, syntax-highlighting, c++

So, Dr. Racket has a very interesting feature where you can see all occurrences of a bound variable if you hover it:

[image: Screencap of Dr Racket showing a definition of the quadratic equation with arrows pointing from the definition of b to its occurrences within the scope]

Is there a way to do something similar in Emacs? I'm currently editing C++ code. It doesn't need to be super-sophisticated: I'd be super-happy with just the local lexical context.

---

This[2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21773/29901) proved really useful to me, but it will highlight any matching words in the entire text, not just the code (let alone the enclosing lexical context.)

Comment: Fancy.  That feels like the sort of feature that the upcoming tree-sitter integration might facilitate.  Maybe `semantic` can already do it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the language. For Javascript, `js2-mode` has a complete language parser and so understand exactly which words really are variables, and which are the correct ones. `js2-refactor` has some functionality that relies on that exact information; I believe it can both highlight all occurrences of a variable and rename it, though it doesn’t draw lines over the top like that.

For C++, I have heard people mention the [`srefactor` package](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor). I’ve never used it though, so I don’t know if it does exactly what you want. You might also be interested in [a general guide](https://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) to related Emacs packages for C/C++ development.

There is also `lsp-mode`, which is all the rage at the moment.

Comment: `srefactor` sounds promising. I'll try it and come back with results